# Get unique value using Quicksight

Tags: unique, calculation, amazon-quicksight

My data has a {NPS} field that I want to get the mean value. Due to my other data in the same dataset, the values are not unique. I want to get the unique {NPS} value from a person into a month, using Quicksight. This is whats the table looks like:

| Date | Person | NPS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nov/21 | P.1 | 10 |
| nov/21 | P.1 | 10 |
| nov/21 | P.2 | 8 |
| feb/22 | P.1 | 9 |

In the end, I want to have something like that:

| Date | Person | NPS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nov/21 | P.1 | 10 |
| null | null | null |
| nov/21 | P.2 | 8 |
| feb/22 | P.1 | 9 |

Comment: This question has been viewed 476 times and no one has left an answer? Did you happen to find the solution?